# Change /dev/shm privileges on Red Hat

Tags: linux, redhat

I suck at Linux and I need your help :)

I have a piece of software that uses `/dev/shm` for whatever reason.
The software cannot be run as `root`.

On my system however `/dev/shm` is owned by `root` and has 755 access mask.

How do I allow everyone to write to `/dev/shm`? 
`chmod` & `chown` won't work for me.

I have Red Hat
(Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64)

Thanks!

Comment: Why won't `chmod` or `chown` work for you?

Comment: I have no idea. Possibly because this is not a regular folder, I don't know.

Comment: Could you paste in the output of `ls -l /dev/shm; chmod 777 /dev/shm; ls -l /dev/shm`?  Adding it to the bottom of your question would be better than commenting.

Comment: why do you need it? is it for audio? I seem to need it for jack or pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem lies in a different place. It seems that jailshell is the one to blaim, showing different access mask to different users for the same file. For that reason, I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the permissions for it in `/etc/fstab` with the mount option `mode` such as:

```
none      /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults,size=8G,mode=777        0 0
```

Comment: I don't have this file in the system.
Should I create it?

Comment: How do you mount /dev/shm?